# Changing the title value of button that takes you to the previous view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have multiple view controllers embedded inside a navigation controller. I have an option that changes the language of the user interface. When user chooses French, the user interface should update itself with French language. All elements are updated with French as I expected, except the button that takes user back to the previous view controller (as you can see in the screenshot - "List of Events").

[image]

This is the function I call to update UI :

```
func updateView() {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
         // CurrentSelection.LanguageUI holds a reference to currenly selected language object
         navigationItem.title = CurrentSelection.languageUI.event_singular 

         navigationController?.title = CurrentSelection.languageUI.listOfEvents <<- this line doesn't work

    }

}
```

The navigationController?.title holds "List of Events" string and the assignment statement seems to work. It just that the UI isn't updated with the new title value. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should be changing the `title` property of each view controller.

Answer (score 0):

It's the previousVC that decides what it's own back button will be.

So set this on the previousVC in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back title" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```

If this isn't set then the back button will be the `.title` of the previous VC.

-

In your situation you should have some kind of language change notification that the previous VC can listen for and know to update its own title.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to implement `UINavigationControllerDelegate` and set the back bar button item there:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.delegate = self
    }

    // MARK: - Navigation controller delegate

    public func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        let item = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Custom title", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        viewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = item
    }
}
```

Something to be aware of is that this needs to be implemented in the view controller which pushes the next view controller. So you'll be changing the back bar button item of the view controller that `willShow`.

Answer (score 0):

Those view controllers in the navigation stack won't change atomatically.

- So you have to use Notification center and add observers to the previous view controllers and change the Title of the navigation bar with selected language when it is called.
- When language is changed you have to post the change.
- Then it will change the title to french so does the back button will
  change.

Comment: I tried your approach and the observer function is called. But, the title change statement doesn't work (self.title = "new title" or navigationController?.title = "new title"). The existing title persists.

Comment: please try navigationItem.title = "hello"